# How to retrieve only the last_modified key in S3 with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to retrieve only the last_modified key from my S3 bucket, in a particular prefix using boto3.

```
# Get Today's date
today = datetime.date.today()

# Get Objects date
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',region_name=AWS_REGION)
bucket = s3.Bucket('xxx')
objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='yyyy').limit(1)

def get_object_check_alarm():
  try:
    for obj in objs:
        print(obj)
        lastobjectdate = (obj.last_modified).date()
  except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    error_code = e.response['Error']['Code']
    if error_code == '404':
        print("There is no file")

  # Compare with defined date
  if today == lastobjectdate:
    print(today)
    print(lastobjectdate)
    print("OK, lastest file comes from today")
  else:
    print(today)
    print(lastobjectdate)
    print("Mail sent")
```

With this code, the current result does not output the last modified key. I've tried to increase the limit() to limit(10), without success.

Comment: I only seeing you printing out the obj itself, never on lastobjectdate. Also, if you got absolutely nothing print out, that means your objs is actually empty list. Check on your Prefix.

Comment: Sorry, I've added missing part of my code, It will be easier to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## --Update Start--

Probably, it might be better to create the objects in S3 with date prefixes.

{bucket}/yyyy/mm/dd/{object}

Example: myS3bucket/2018/12/29/myfile.txt

With this approach, your query becomes simple to find out if you got any files for that particular day and also the number files list you retrieve becomes short.

```
prefix="/"+str(today.year)+"/"+str(today.month)+"/"+str(today.day)+"/"
objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix).all()
```

## --Update Complete--

I am not sure you gave full code but there are some indentation issues in above snippet. I just tested below and it works fine and I get correct `last_modified` date.

Please make sure you are on correct region as bucket. Also `last_modified` is in `UTC` timezone so your comparison should consider that.

```
import boto3
from datetime import date
import botocore

# Get Today's date
today = date.today()
# Get Objects date
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',region_name='us-east-1')
bucket = s3.Bucket('xxxx')
prefix="/"+str(today.year)+"/"+str(today.month)+"/"+str(today.day)+"/"
objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix).all()

def get_object_check_alarm():
    try:
        for obj in objs:
            print(obj)
            lastobjectdate = (obj.last_modified).date()
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        error_code = e.response['Error']['Code']
        if error_code == '404':
            print("There is no file")

# Compare with defined date
    if today == lastobjectdate:
        print(today)
        print(lastobjectdate)
        print("OK, lastest file comes from today")
    else:
        print(today)
        print(lastobjectdate)
        print("Mail sent")

get_object_check_alarm()
```

Below is the the output. I am in EST zone so date is still 12/28 but object creation date came in as 12/29 since its already 12/29 in UTC zone when object was created.

> s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='xxxx', key='yyyy/')
>
> 2018-12-28
>
> 2018-12-29
>
> Mail sent

Comment: Works better if I use : objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='prefix').all()

Comment: yep. it works better with all(). Also, I updated my answer with best practice approach of creating objects in S3. I know you are looking for last_modified ones so if you update same file just modified date gets changed with old date prefix only. Just wanted to give you some idea.